# Is define_method thread safe?

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming

I was hoping to create something as follows:

```rb
class TheClass
  def initialize(attributes)
    @attribute = attributes
  end

  def method_missing(name, *_args, &_block)
    super unless @attributes.key?(name)

    self.class.define_method(name) { @attributes[name] }
  end
end
```

and was wondering if I needed to add define_method in a mutex or not.

Comment: Not an answer but why define_method at all why not just use `@attributes.key?(name) ? @attributes[name] : super`? Also might want to standardize the hash keys e.g. all strings or all symbols because `@attributes.key?(:name)` is not the same as `@attributes.key?("name")`

Comment: @engineersmnky, the reason for define_method is that subsequent calls will be faster. `method_missing` is known for being slower than method definitions.

Comment: But define_method is literally defining a method for any instance of that class so each call with a different Hash will result in compounding method definitions. If this was the goal then why not just define them in initialization and be done with it rather than arbitrarily define them upon invocation?

Comment: If you're worried about speed, consider using respond_to?

Answer (score 1):

Since you're defining a method on the *class* and not the specific instance of that one object, I assume you're intending to define a method on *every instance* of that class, potentially being used across multiple threads.

The answer to your question is: No, it's not.

In fact, that code won't even work in that way I described above. What'll happen is the new methods will be defined for *future* instances of that class, but the current nor old instances.

For functional, performance, style, grep-ability, maintainability, and readability reasons, you really should just use a `Hash`.